# How do I find the read only backcolor of a textbox in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, colors, panel, disabled-control

I have a situation in VB.Net where I have a couple of text boxes inside of panels.

I need to set the textboxes to read only and have them grayed out. The problem is that the boxes are inside panels so I need the panel to change to the same color as the text box.

However, the default "grayed out" color of a read only textbox is not the same on all OS's and desktop styles.

For example;

When I check the color of the read only textbox on my PC its color is `#D4D0C7` and the exact same box on another person's PC in my office (both Using Windows 7, but with different desktop styles) is `#F1F1F1`.

So how to I set the color of the panel to match this default color of the text box?

Comment: you could try `SystemColors,Control`  This might confuse the user though since *your* disabled control wont be using the color they are accustomed to seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour is being picked up from the [SystemColors collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It appears to be `SystemColors.Control` which you can see if you set a textbox to `ReadOnly = True` at design time and examine the `BackColor` property

These colours can change according to each users profile settings.

Comment: @user2721815 proper "thanks" on SO is to click the checkmark and upvote the answer